# Bind data to form Ionic Date and number

Tags: angular, ionic3

I make form has value date and other number
when I bind Date it dose not bind, and the number has shown but in different language i should rewrite the number
Here is the code:

```
private initializeForm() {
    let Porn = new Date();
    let PornNo = 0;
    let deadNo = 0;


    if (this.mode == 'Edit') {
        console.log(this.rabbit.Porn.toString());
        if (this.rabbit.Porn != null) {
            Porn = this.rabbit.Porn;
        }
        else
            Porn = new Date();//this.rabbit.Porn;
        if (this.rabbit.PornNo != null)
            PornNo = parseInt(this.rabbit.PornNo.toString());
        if (this.rabbit.deadNo != null)
            deadNo = parseInt(this.rabbit.deadNo.toString());
    }

    this.rabbitForm = new FormGroup({
        'Porn': new FormControl(Porn, Validators.required),
        'PornNo': new FormControl(PornNo, Validators.required),
        'deadNo': new FormControl(deadNo, Validators.required)
    });
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.mode = this.navParams.get('mode');
    if (this.mode == 'Edit') {
        this.rabbit = this.navParams.get('rabbit');
        //this.txtPostion = this.rabbit.PositionId;
        this.index = this.navParams.get('index');
    }
    this.initializeForm();
}
```

Here is The View

```
<form [formGroup]="rabbitForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="Porn" [(ngModel)]="rabbit.Porn"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>number babie</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number"
                       formControlName="PornNo" [(ngModel)]="txtPornNo"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>number babie dead</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number"
                       formControlName="deadNo" [(ngModel)]="txtdeadNo"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button type="submit"
            ion-button
            block
            [disabled]="!rabbitForm.valid">
        {{ mode }} Save
    </button>
</form>

enter code here
```

I need to bind Date and number correctly
[image: View]

I make form has value date and other number
when I bind Date it dose not bind, and the number has shown but in different language i should rewrite the number

Comment: can you show the error also? and do you need the date and number in submit function?

Comment: its not error but it dose not bind date value < and number bind like in other language i must rewrite number

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form [formGroup]="rabbitForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="Porn"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>number babie</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number"
                   formControlName="PornNo"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>number babie dead</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" formControlName="deadNo" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button type="submit"
        ion-button
        block
        [disabled]="!rabbitForm.valid">
    {{ mode }} Save
</button>
```

`